# Linse Numbers and mysql COUNT don't work together with BASH

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql

I am trying to calculate a number result from the Mysql with the number of lines in a particular file:

`Counter=$(mysql -u USER -p'PASWORD' -s -N -h localhost -e "select COUNT(*) from Database.LOOKUP where LookupResults = 'MM'")`

`echo "Counter is : "`

`echo $Counter` 
#3

`echo " This is Total lines"`

`CountLines= grep -c $ /home/Desktop/Example.csv` #10

`num=$(($CountLines+ $Counter | bc))`

`echo $num`

The result is :

`Counter is :` 
3

`This is Total lines:`
10

`This is Total Numbers 3 + 10:`

There is a space when I try to print $CountLines+ $Counter , it should be : 13

I am using Ubuntu server + Mysql DB and BASH

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up shell arithmetic and `bc` arithmetic.

**Either** use

```
num=$(( CountLines + Counter ))
```

(the `$`s for variable de-referencing are optional in this case)

**or**

```
num=$( echo "$CountLines + $Counter" | bc )
```

Comment: If I used num=$(( CountLines + Counter )) I would get This is the Count
3
This is the Total Lines
10
This is Total Numbers 3 + 10:
3
If I used num=$( echo "$CountLines + $Counter" | bc ) I would get This is the CountThis is the Count
3
This is the Total Lines
10
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
This is Total Numbers 3 + 10:

Answer (score -2):

I just changed ( CountLines ) to ( Test ) and it worked great!!